# Create spacing between checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox, panel

I'm auto generating checkboxes and putting them into a panel,but when I do that, they all appear at the same point.  I can manually move them apart, but this could cause problems down the line.  Is there a way to get them to automatically align under each other.

Here's my code:

```
foreach (Category i in DesktopApp.getBaseCat())
{
    checkBox = new CatBox();
    checkBox.setCat(i);
    checkBox.Text = i.ToString();  // puts the name of the category in the text field
    checkBox.Click += new EventHandler(simpleCatBox_Click);
    this.categoryPanel.Controls.Add(checkBox);     // adds it to the panel
    step++;                                        // increments step
}
```

Comment: You could use a FlowLayoutPanel

Answer (score 0):

Give the checkbox a margin (10px in this example)

```
 checkBox.Margin = new Thinkness(10);
```

Or, if you want different margins

```
checkBox.Margin = new Thickness(left,top,right,bottom);
```

Comment: I get an error saying "The type or namespace name 'Thickness' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"